# Discord bot command works some times

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, dotenv

I am pretty new to `discord.py` thing and I am building a bot that can I shut down on command(but that doesn't turn off/make bot offline, it just disables it's functions). so I made this `shutdown()` command and sometimes works and other times it doesn't for some to me unknown reason. Some prints don't work either for some reason, I will mark them in the code:

```
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
import random

load_dotenv()

token = 'bot token'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('-----------------------------------')
    print('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))
    print('-----------------------------------')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("pong")

@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *args):
    response = ""

    for arg in args:
        response = response + " " + arg

    await ctx.channel.send(response)

@bot.command()
async def shutdown(ctx):#this command doesn't work properly
    await bot.close()
    print("We have logged off as {0.user}".format(bot))#this print doesn't work most of the time

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "opinion":
        await message.channel.send("not an opinion")

bot.run(token)
```

Thanks in forward!Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You probably want `bot.logout()` not `.close()`

Comment: @effprime `Bot.logout` is just an alias for `Bot.close`, take a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.logout)

Answer (score 1):

Your bot is not processing the commands (other commands should also not work), you should add `bot.process_commands` at  the **end** of the `on_message` event.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # ...

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

#### Reference:

-[`Bot.process_commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)